# Getting Facebook comments "From" field using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When getting comments for a page post from the `Graph API`, I do:

```
 [post_id]/comments?fields=message,from{name,picture}
```

I am using the `page_access_token` for the page and it has been working since a couple of days ago then I notice that I am suddenly not getting results from the `from` field. I tried switching to lower versions of the API (currently 2.12, tried up until 2.9) and tried using the business manager token instead of the `page_access_token`. I tried searching online if there has been any recent change that would've caused but haven't found any.

I'm wondering how other people go about getting comments data for a post that can help?

Edit:
Answers to similar questions say to use a Page Token, which I have been doing.

Comment: Thing is, I have been using a 'page_access_token' but I'm still getting no 'From'.

Comment: It could be an issue with your token, have you extended it to a never-expire page token?